# Checkers games with computer random movement

Tags: java, movement, random, board-game

Im studying Java OOP, and I have to make first assignment about making checkers board game. I have to get input from user if he plays, and than when his turn is over the computer will play. Computer's movement is random but if he has the opportunity to "eat" his rival, he has to do this and if not than making random move. 
Can someone help me with the coding?

Comment: On which part are you stuck exactly right now?

Comment: Computer turn, how can I write the code of selection random cell from line 2, for the first movement

Comment: What have you tried so far? It could be even written as one-liner such as `tokens.stream().collect(Collectors.collectingAndThen(Collectors.toList(), list -> Collections.shuffle(list).stream())).findFirst(token -> token.canMove())`.

Comment: @wondra That is terrifying and exciting at the same time. Congrats

Comment: hey, I have learned only Java and C programs. Have no idea what does it means. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way would be to build a list of all possible moves and then randomly select from them.

1. Initialize two empty lists, eatMoves and nonEatMoves
2. For each rival token:

   - For each possible move of that token:

     - if the move involves eating an opponent:

       - Add move to eatMoves
     - else:

       - Add move to nonEatMoves
3. Choose one of the moves:

   - If eatMoves is not empty:

     - Randomly choose from eatMoves list
   - else:

     - Randomly choose from nonEatMoves list
4. Return the random move selection

Actually choosing a random number is straightforward: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Random.html

Comment: Hey, I've made it already, but Im strugeling to find the right code for the random. I know that this is the best way to 'start' computer first move. After using random, I'll use IF loops and FOR .